# Returning a value from a matched cell of separate sheet

Tags: excel

I have two sheets of numerous lines of data. I would like to find an exact match of cell a1 (sheet1) from column b (sheet 2). If there is a match, then return the value of column c of the corresponding/matching cell in sheet 2.

if a1 sheet 1 is the same as b2 sheet 2, then b1 sheet 1 equals the value in column c of the row from of b2.

Example:
A1 sheet 1 equals 1140c0114
B2 sheet 2 equals 1140c0114
C2 sheet 2 equals "INFO"
Therefore, B1 sheet 1 = "INFO"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple VLOOKUP

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!B:C,2,0)
```

Comment: Thank you. What do I do if I want to return the value from cell f instead of c? This is were I am having a problem if the cells are not next to each other.

Comment: @user3680257 No problem. `VLOOKUP` is a relatively simple function, go ahead and read a bit about it in the VBA Help or anywhere on the internet, e.g. [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/excel-vlookup-formula.htm). For your next question the correct formula would be `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!B:F,5,0)`. The lookup range starts with the column you match against and has to contain the column you wish to return. The third parameter tells which column you wish to return in the lookup range's relative reference (5 starting from B).
If you find this answer correct please mark it as accepted. Thank you.